# Firebug can't see display:block attribute of an element?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I was inspecting code on this page with firebug:

http://www.phppennyauctiondemo.com/

On the top right corner, there is a "Register" button and a link within it.

When i select the link with firebug, in the "Style" section of firebug, I can't find the display:block attribute even though I know it's there (it can be found on "Computed" part of firebug where it clearly says, display: block).

So if links have a default inline display, and it hasn't been changed with css, how come this element has a display:block? What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you post the pertinent code directly in this question?  If the linked website no longer has the code in question, this question won't make any sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you scroll down the Style section for that element, you'll notice this second rule:

```
#header .top-menu li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0.35em 0;
}
```

The `float` declaration is what turns the link into a block element, as floated elements are implicitly `display: block` (as computed).